# How to check MySQL returned an empty result set?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am curious if my `query` returns an `empty result set` and my `fetching method` is `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` what is the actual `value` of that as it is fetched in an `array`? Is it just `false` or an `empty array` or `0` ?

And how can I check that let´s say in the following context: 
`$ajResult = $query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` `if ($ajResult ???? ) {....} else {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> PDOStatement::rowCount — Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

```
if ($query1->rowCount() > 0) {
  // not empty
} else {
   echo 'nothing';
}
```

Since [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array, you can use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to get the number of rows returned from the query.

```
if (count($ajResult)) {...}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$query1` as `$ajResult` is the return value from the `fetchAll`?

Comment: Thanks I have changed it.

Comment: be careful using PDOStatement::rowCount... it returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications. See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 1):

`fetchAll` returns an array of the rows, so if the array has 0 elements...

```
if ( count($ajResult) == 0 ) {....} else {}
```